# Getting a precise percent from two Big Integers

Tags: c#, math, biginteger

This obviously doesn't work.

```
BigInteger Total = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022234235423534543;
BigInteger Actual = 83450348250384508349058934085;
string Percent = ((Decimal)100.0/Total*Actual).ToString()+"%";
```

The question is, how to I get my precise percent?

Currently I use..

```
        string sTotal = (task.End - task.Start).ToString();
        BigInteger current = task.End;

                string sCurrent = (task.End-current).ToString().PadLeft(sTotal.Length, '0');
                Int32 maxLength = sCurrent.Length;
                if (maxLength > Int64.MaxValue.ToString().Length - 1)
                    maxLength = Int64.MaxValue.ToString().Length - 1;

                UInt64 currentI = Convert.ToUInt64(sCurrent.Substring(0, maxLength));
                UInt64 totalI = Convert.ToUInt64(sTotal.Substring(0, maxLength));

                Percent = (Decimal)100.0 / totalI
                    * currentI;
```

Can you suggest better?

Comment: How many places do you want it accurate to?

Comment: I hope you can use some floating point types instead of BigInteger (with some additional magic).

Comment: @EricLippert 56 digits or more

Comment: @HopeNick that would be much nicer, im not too good at that :-)

Comment: @Chris: Since a double is only accurate to 15 digits and a decimal is only accurate to 29 digits, you are going to have to write the math yourself I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're computing a rational, not an integer, so you should install the Solver Foundation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524509(v=VS.93).aspx

and use Rational rather than BigInteger:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff526610(v=vs.93).aspx

You can then call ToDouble if you want to get the rational as the nearest double.

> I need it accurate to 56 decimal places

OK, that is a ridiculous amount of precision, but I'll take you at your word.

Since a double has only 15 decimal places of precision and a decimal only 29, you can't use double or decimal. You're going to have to write the code yourself to do the division.

Here are two ways to do it:

First, write an algorithm that emulates doing long division. You can do it by hand, so you can write a computer program to do it. Keep going until you generate the required number of bits of precision.

Second: WOLOG assume that the rational in question is positive and is of the form `x` / `y` where `x` and `y` are big integers.  Let `b` be 10<sup>p</sup> for a desired precision `p`. You wish to find the big integer `a` with the property that:

```
a * y < b * x
```

and

```
b * x < (a + 1) * y
```

Either `a/b` or `(a+1)/b` is the decimal fraction with p digits closest to `x/y`.

Make sense?

You can find the value of `a` by doing a binary search over the set of non-negative BigIntegers.

To do the binary search, first you have to find upper and lower bounds. Lower is easy enough; you know that 0 is a lower bound because by assumption the fraction `x/y` is positive. To find the upper bound, try `1/b`, `10/b`, `100/b` ... and so on until you find a value that is larger than `x/y`. Now you have an upper and lower bound, and you can binary search the resulting space to find the exact value of `a` that makes the inequalities true.

Comment: although I am not good at math, this at least improves my existing solution. thankyou

Comment: @Chris: You're welcome. My advice is: get good at math. You will find it helps your computer programming immensely. Do you understand why those inequalities give you the fraction that you seek?